# What is the IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL ifcfg directive and under what scenarios would I want to use it?

Tags: linux, rhel

CentOS / RHEL 6

I recently learned that there's a ifcfg directive called `IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL` exists for use in the files located here: `/etc/sysconfig/networking-scripts/ifcfg-*`. But I'm having a difficult time finding information about it.

- What does it do?
- Under what circumstances would I ever want it set to "yes"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Fedora Project's wiki page on [Anaconda Networking](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Network):

> If both IPv4 and IPv6 configuration is enabled, failing IPv4
>   configuration of activated device means that activation is considered
>   as failing overall (which corresponds to Require IPv4 addressing for
>   this connection to complete checked in nm-c-e or
>   `IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes` in ifcfg file).

Putting it another way it's saying that if a connection is setup for both IPv4 and IPv6, with this option set to `yes`, the setup of the said connection will be reported as failed, even if IPv6 is setup, and IPv4 is not.